# The image map in my project is not working

Tags: html, imagemap

The image map doesn't work in my project, so there is no area to click on on the image.

Code:

```
<td>
  <map name="map" id="map">
    <area alt="" title="" href="stat1.php" shape="rect" coords="51,568,116,618" />
    <area alt="" title="" href="stat2.php" shape="rect" coords="140,567,202,612" />
    <area alt="" title="" href="stat3.php" shape="rect" coords="226,568,290,613" />
    <area alt="" title="" href="stat4.php" shape="rect" coords="51,627,116,676" />
    <area alt="" title="" href="stat5.php" shape="rect" coords="139,626,204,677" />
    <area alt="" title="" href="stat6.php" shape="rect" coords="225,627,292,677" />
  </map>
  <img src="img/commander6.png" usemap="#map" width="95%"/>
</td>
```

I also tried it the other way around, so the `<img/>` tag was before the `<map>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove

```
 width="95%"
```